# scroll event not firing on div element in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have tried everything I can think of to get this event to trigger when scrolling on the div tag. I made sure that it was actually reaching this code and it does. It never triggers when scrolling though. I also tried using .scroll(...) and .bind('scroll'...) Any thoughts on what the issue is?

```
$('.ScrollIEContainer').scroll(function ()
{
   var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (scrollPos != null && scrollPos != undefined)
   {
      $(this).contents('table.GridView').children('thead').children('tr').css({ 'top': scrollPos + 'px' });
   }
});
```

The goal here is to update the top position of the header in my grid view to implement fixed header scrolling.

UPDATE:
I have been unable to debug any of this code with the exception of alert statements for some inexplicable reason but I was able to debug and use the watch window to check on my selector elements by inserting a a line of code right before it that would result in a Null Reference exception (WTF). Anyways, I looked at the dom inside my element and the onscroll event is null event after  the code above is executed.

Comment: What is the `topScroll` function? Is that supposed to be `scrollTop`? Are you sure you're not getting errors in your js console on scroll?

Comment: @jball topScroll() is part of the jquery api. it is the scrollTop dom attribute. There are no errors with that code.

Comment: @jball I misread what you were asking haha. Didn't even read that part where you said .. "it supposed to be scrollTop" I just breezed past thinking you were asking more about the code =(

Comment: @jball it is fricken frustrating bc for some inexplicable reason the javascript engine won't even let me debug this section of code ... i have had to resort to alert statements.

Comment: @Matthew Cox it's all good - we all go snowblind staring at code from time to time. I've made similar mistakes before too.

Comment: @jball this particular event is only meant to trigger if it is IE .. I omitted the code that checks if it is IE first ... then call this section. So I really need to ensure that it works specifically in IE ... Yet the js engine has just decided i cannot debug this particular segment.

Comment: Did you answer karim79's question?  Do you have your jquery code wrapped in $(document).ready(function(){ /*CODE HERE*/})?  That would explain why debug code isn't working.

Comment: @nzifnab yes I did answer it. see the third comment directed at him. Why would that cause that to happen?

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't see.  It could have been because the document wasn't fully loaded when you were trying to register your event handler (ie. your element was on the page yet)... but I guess that's not the case in your situation sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's `live` doesn't support `scroll`

Is your element dynamically added?

**Edited:**

Change `$(this).topScroll()` to `$(this).scrollTop()`

Comment: @tnc lame that it is not supported but no it is not dynamically added so I shouldn't really need it be live.

Comment: @tnc i edited both lines of code to what you see in my OP now ... it still does not fire =(

Comment: Have you tried alerting what the scrollTop is (or console) - and verifying that's getting set?

Comment: @tnc before I get to that point ... it would be prudent to figure out how to correct the issue of it not triggering a scroll event =D

Comment: $('.ScrollIEContainer').scroll(function () doesn't fire it?  If not, can you post a jsfiddle of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example with a div.  Notice that the headers position is relative to its parent.  Your problem may simply lie with the thead not responding to this positioning though.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        .fixed-div {
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: grey;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .header {
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: red;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".fixed-div").scroll(function(event) {
                var y = $(this).scrollTop();
                var x = $(this).scrollLeft();
                $(".header").css({
                    top: y,
                    left: x
                });
            });

        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="fixed-div">
        <div class="header">Header</div>
        <ul>
            <li>0</li>
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
            <li>4</li>
            <li>5</li>
            <li>6</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```